# Using maven to rebuild local sources from other projects in dev environment

Tags: java, maven, ant, build

We have a microservice architecture where the entire project looks as follows:

```
+- Utilities
+- Service A REST
+- Service A Backend
+- Service B REST
+- Service B Backend
...
+- Service X REST
+- Service X Backend
```

Each of these is an independent Maven project that can be independently developed.

It so happens, of course, that some of the projects may have to use classes from another one (e.g. to be able to give back corresponding `Exception` classes in error messages).

Thus one of the projects may have the following dependencies:

```
Service A backend
+- dependency 1
+- dependency 2
...
\- Utilities
\- Service B backend
```

In a standard deployment, we would use a Maven repository and simply add the latest `jar`s as dependencies. The problem is during development: if we make a change in `Service B backend`, a dependency of `Service A backend`, we cannot simply do `mvn compile Service-A-backend` because `Service B backend` will not be recompiled. Doing this for every single project during development is extremely error-prone.

Eclipse might be able to work around this by having the project on the build path, but we do not want to bind ourselves to an IDE and would like to ideally be able to solve the issue with Maven itself.

Can you use Maven in the above scenario so that you can list `Service B backend` above as a `source` dependency where, if we `compile` or `package` `Service A backend`, its local source dependencies also get recompiled if there have been any changes? If not, can you do it with `gradle` or `ant`?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider looking at the Maven [modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) feature. Here is an example of use in a POM file:

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    ....
</modules>
```

I personally use in addition to maven modules (for compilation ) git [sub-module](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for pull/push code base on multiple project feature.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was however under the impression that to use the `modules` feature, each of the underlying services would need to have a parent pom. We are also using Spring Boot, which already has a parent pom, so we would need multiple parents for each service which seems very impractical.

Comment: you may creates a parent pom that have a spring boot parent itself